# Course provider

Tags: vocabulary

You are due to move into a rented apartment next month but you will not be able to because you have some problems.

Write a letter to the course provider.

What does a course provider means in this letter question

Comment: It is difficult to understand what a **course provider** has to do with renting apartments. A course provider is someone who organises courses of one kind or another. As it stands the description makes no sense. Presumably the letter would have to be addressed to the owner of the apartment or the agency concerned.

Comment: Is the **course provider** the landlord of the apartment? Perhaps a **school** provides rooms to students. Or is this a badly phrased school assignment in which you are to write a letter as if it were to the landlord in this hypothetical situation and then hand it in to the **teacher** of a class? Without more context, it's impossible to tell if *course provider* means *school* or *teacher*.

Answer (score 0):

A "course provider" is someone who is providing a particular course.  In common usage, this would be a teacher providing a course of study.

In the context of your question, I believe that you are being asked to write a letter to your teacher.  This letter should explain the situation with your apartment, and the problems that are keeping you from moving in.